# How does a TransactionScope implementation work? What database support is required?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, transactions, transactionscope

Just reading up on [TransactionScope implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx).

Could someone confirm if this technique is driven by client-side .net, or if it requires something special from specific DB Vendors? Is this a SQL Server only thing?

Comment: At least for a non-distributed (and non-nested) TS it is just thread-local transaction information that's automatically set for the commands, etc. Never quite sure how nested/distributed scopes work... might want to focus on a specific *aspect* of TS, because even DTC isn't available in all SQL Server isolation levels.

Comment: @pst: what do you mean by non-nested.  like a one-level transaction?  Do they mark / query the thread somehow to discover if there's an existing transaction in play?

Comment: Well, it's all done with thread-local information (to handle the dynamic scoping), but that was me hedging my bets -- not all databases support nestable transactions for instance.

Comment: (Well, "nestable" = "concurrent transactions" would be a better fit in this case.)

Comment: @pst: like if you were to implement this yourself does doing a static lookup on Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID sound appropriate?  Is that a unique ID?

Comment: @pst: if you want the points, please post an answer.

Comment: I'm waiting for a good answer ;-) I would look at the source for the SQLite (and maybe Postgres, etc.) adapters to see how they implement it and/or what they document as issues. I imagine it's all handled through various "enlisting" interfaces.

Comment: However, as far as TLS for data there is [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) (as of .NET 4) or see [Thread Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh(v=vs.90).aspx) for .NET 2 approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If your question also includes RDBMS vendors, then SQL Server Compact supports it and so does Oracle.

Comment: I should focus the question a bit more.  I'm interested in who implements it, but more importantly on the implementation.  For example, is it hard to reterofit a DBMS that doesn't implement (if indeed it is a DBMS specific think).  The MS documentation that I've seen so far is quite bland on this topic.